# Line feed converts to carriage return in file generated via XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a small XSLT that converts XML to a txt file.  The problem I have is that the line feed characters are being converted to a carriage return.  I can see this when the file is open with a hex editor. I have also tried using encoding set to ISO-8859-1.  Please note that when the file is opened in the editor (Ultraedit) it asks the question "Do you want to convert file to DOS format?" which indicates that the LF's are missing. Any assistance would be very much appreciated.  Thanks.

```
<xsl:template name="process_STATEMENTS">
    <xsl:text>Line 1</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xd;</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>Line 2</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xd;&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>Line 3</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: did you set the output method to text?

Comment: What XSLT processor are you using? I am not able to repro this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question "Do you want to convert file to DOS format?" suggests to me that the file is using x0A (newline or line feed) as its line ending, rather than x0D (carriage return) as you suggest - could you check?

Note that the XSLT/XQuery serialization spec gives processors some latitude here: the description of the text serialization method says "A newline character in the instance of the data model MAY be output using any character sequence that is conventionally used to represent a line ending in the chosen system environment.".